# Laravel 6 return empty array after MySql stored procedure call

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 6.2 and I have the following code in my controller

```
$date_ini='01-01-2022';
$date_fin='31-12-2022';

$seg=\DB::select('CALL pr_SegOrder(?,?,?)',[$client,$date_ini,$date_fin]);

return $seg;
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pr_SegOrder`(`client` varchar(200), `date_ini` datetime, `date_fin` datetime)
BEGIN
 SELECT cod,norder 
FROM
  order op 
WHERE
cast(op.created_at as date) BETWEEN @date_ini AND @date_fin 

ORDER BY
    op.cod asc ;
END
```

If I execute my query on MySql everything works fine. When I execute the SP from Laravel there is no error message, just an empty result.

The problem only ocurring when i use date parameters, because if only send "client" parameter from laravel, works fine.

any idea what could occurring?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, procedure input arguments like `date_ini` do not use the `@` sigil. That character is for [user-defined session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). They are not the same variable.

When you used the expression `BETWEEN @date_ini AND @date_fin`, those two variables probably have the value NULL, unless you had set their value in the session before calling the procedure.

So just use `BETWEEN date_ini AND date_fin`, without the `@` characters. Then they will be references to the procedure input arguments.

Be careful not to name your procedure arguments the same as columns in the tables, or else your query will refer to the columns, not the variables.

Comment: Thanks, works fine do not using @ sigil. But I've the same problem when i pase Year argument to stored procedure. CREATE DEFINER PROCEDURE `pr_SegOrder`(`date_fin` datetime, time_year INTEGER)